# Code Optimization - data.table, current for loop with multiple reference to be optimized into data.table

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, optimization, data.table

I have a requirement, where in I have a huge database of around **2 million** records where in I need to create new variables with codes based on information from another data frame for some specific variables. So the situation is -

1. Have a reference database which contains cutoffs for variables by IBD (**inter1**)
2. Have a vector that contains list of variables for whom codes needs to be created based on the cutoffs (**v0int**)
3. Main database on which new variables with codes based on cutoffs needs to be created (**smpl**)

So for example for an IBD **5** and variable **var1a** consider below information  in **inter1** file -

```
IBD var1a
5    11
5    18
5    30
5    63
```

Based on above information I want to create a new variable in **smpl** data frame such that -

```
if smpl$var1a <= 11 then var1a_INT = 1
if smpl$var1a > 11 & smpl$var1a <= 18 then var1a_INT = 2
if smpl$var1a > 18 & smpl$var1a <= 30 then var1a_INT = 3
if smpl$var1a > 30 & smpl$var1a <= 63 then var1a_INT = 4
if smpl$var1a > 63 then var1a_INT = 5
```

Since this needs to be done for multiple variables and by IBD, I have written my code using **for loop**. My sample code is as below -

```
    set.seed(1200)

    IBD <- sort(rep(1:10,4))

    var1a <- c()
    var2a <- c()
    var3a <- c()
    var4a <- c()
    var5a <- c()

    j=10
    for (i in 1:10){
      set.seed(1200)+(j*i)
      var1 <- sort(sample(1:(10*i),4))
      var2 <- sort(sample(11:(15*i),4))
      var3 <- sort(sample(10:(17*i),4))
      var4 <- sort(sample(11:(19*i),4))
      var5 <- sort(sample(10:(16*i),4))

      var1a <- c(var1a,var1)
      var2a <- c(var2a,var2)
      var3a <- c(var3a,var3)
      var4a <- c(var4a,var4)
      var5a <- c(var5a,var5)
    }

    inter1 <- data.frame(IBD,var1a,var2a,var3a,var4a,var5a)

    sm=5000

    ID <- seq(1:sm)
    IBD <- sample(1:10,sm,replace = T)
    CELL <- sample(1001:9999,sm)
    var1a <- sample(1:150,sm,replace = T)
    var2a <- sample(1:200,sm,replace = T)
    var3a <- sample(1:200,sm,replace = T)
    var4a <- sample(1:350,sm,replace = T)
    var5a <- sample(1:250,sm,replace = T)
    var6a <- sample(1:150,sm,replace = T)
    var7a <- sample(1:250,sm,replace = T)
    var8a <- sample(1:350,sm,replace = T)
    var9a <- sample(1:450,sm,replace = T)
    loc <- sample(1:20,sm,replace = T)
    bill <- sample(1:2,sm,replace = T)

        smpl <- data.frame(ID,IBD,CELL,var1a,var2a,var3a,var4a,var5a,var6a,var7a,var8a,var9a,loc,bill)



    v0int <- c("var1a","var2a","var3a","var4a","var5a")

    df_smpl <- data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow = 0,ncol = ncol(smpl)))

    #l=1
    start_time <- Sys.time()

        for (l in (unique(inter1$IBD))){
      df1 <- subset(smpl,IBD == l)
      for (k in 1:length(v0int)){
        #k=1
        q0 <- v0int[k]
        q1 <- sort(inter1[inter1$IBD == l,q0])
        for (m in 1:nrow(df1)){
          #print(q0)
          #print(l)
          #print(m)
          if (length(q1) == 0){
            df1[m,paste0(q0,"_INT")]=NA
          } else if(length(q1) == 1){
            if(!is.null(df1[m,q0]) & df1[m,"IBD"]==l & df1[m,q0] <= q1[1]) df1[m,paste0(q0,"_INT")]=1
            if(!is.null(df1[m,q0]) & df1[m,"IBD"]==l & df1[m,q0] > q1[1]) df1[m,paste0(q0,"_INT")]=2
          } else if(length(q1) == 2){
            if(!is.null(df1[m,q0]) & df1[m,"IBD"]==l & df1[m,q0] <= q1[1]) df1[m,paste0(q0,"_INT")]=1
            if(!is.null(df1[m,q0]) & df1[m,"IBD"]==l & df1[m,q0] > q1[1] & df1[m,q0] <= q1[2]) df1[m,paste0(q0,"_INT")]=2
            if(!is.null(df1[m,q0]) & df1[m,"IBD"]==l & df1[m,q0] > q1[2]) df1[m,paste0(q0,"_INT")]=3
          } else if(length(q1) == 3) {
            if(!is.null(df1[m,q0]) & df1[m,"IBD"]==l & df1[m,q0] <= q1[1]) df1[m,paste0(q0,"_INT")]=1
            if(!is.null(df1[m,q0]) & df1[m,"IBD"]==l & df1[m,q0] > q1[1] & df1[m,q0] <= q1[2]) df1[m,paste0(q0,"_INT")]=2
            if(!is.null(df1[m,q0]) & df1[m,"IBD"]==l & df1[m,q0] > q1[2] & df1[m,q0] <= q1[3]) df1[m,paste0(q0,"_INT")]=3
            if(!is.null(df1[m,q0]) & df1[m,"IBD"]==l & df1[m,q0] > q1[3]) df1[m,paste0(q0,"_INT")]=4
          } else if(length(q1) == 4) {
            if(!is.null(df1[m,q0]) & df1[m,"IBD"]==l & df1[m,q0] <= q1[1]) df1[m,paste0(q0,"_INT")]=1
            if(!is.null(df1[m,q0]) & df1[m,"IBD"]==l & df1[m,q0] > q1[1] & df1[m,q0] <= q1[2]) df1[m,paste0(q0,"_INT")]=2
            if(!is.null(df1[m,q0]) & df1[m,"IBD"]==l & df1[m,q0] > q1[2] & df1[m,q0] <= q1[3]) df1[m,paste0(q0,"_INT")]=3
            if(!is.null(df1[m,q0]) & df1[m,"IBD"]==l & df1[m,q0] > q1[3] & df1[m,q0] <= q1[4]) df1[m,paste0(q0,"_INT")]=4
            if(!is.null(df1[m,q0]) & df1[m,"IBD"]==l & df1[m,q0] > q1[4]) df1[m,paste0(q0,"_INT")]=5
          }
        }
        #q1 <- NULL
      }
      df_smpl <- rbind(df_smpl,df1)
      #q0 <- NULL
    }


    time_taken <- as.numeric(difftime(Sys.time(), start_time, units = 'secs'))
```

For sample data of **5000** records this takes **5.859623** seconds on my machine which is having 16GB RAM SSD HDD with 2 cores.

When tried for a data with **500000** records this takes **752.7261** seconds.

My actual data is having **2 million** records and I need to run this in a iterative manner multiple times so the time needed would increase in a big way.

On doing some search I understand **data.table** is much faster and saves huge amount of time. I do not know **data.table** very well and want to seek your help on this.

It would be a huge help and huge time saving if we can optimize this code.

Comment: Hi, you need to provide more information on your current environment I think - where is the data at present?

Comment: @MandyShaw, Thank you for looking into this. Data is present locally in my machine in csv format.

Comment: @Roland, could you please guide how you managed to get the post right. I mean I had indent my codes and it was not allowing me to post and it seems you edited few lines. What exactly you did that it worked

Comment: Hi, I won't be able to look into it myself (not a R person) but knowing where the data is will undoubtedly help others. But even I can see that manipulating lots of data in a csv file is bound to be slow, you will need a specialised data store.

Comment: You can see [what I did](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51670643/revisions), but I don't know which part solved the problem you report. Possibly removing the superfluous backticks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example data I got the same results using this loop:

```
for (l in (unique(inter1$IBD))){
  df1 <- subset(smpl, IBD == l)
  for (k in 1:length(v0int)){
    q0 <- v0int[k]
    q1 <- sort(inter1[inter1$IBD == l,q0])
    x <- as.integer(cut(df1[, q0], c(0, q1, Inf)))
    df1[, paste0(q0,"_INT")] <- x
  }
  df_smpl <- rbind(df_smpl, df1)
}
```

0.42 sek vs 10 sek

Using `data.table` we can easily add the results straight to the original data table. Which will be mush faster than using `rbind`.

```
setDT(smpl) # convert smpl to data.table
setkey(smpl, IBD) # setkey on IBD for faster `IBD == l` operation

start_time <- Sys.time()

for (l in (unique(inter1$IBD))) {
  for (k in 1:length(v0int)) {
    q0 <- v0int[k]
    q1 <- sort(inter1[inter1$IBD == l, q0])
    smpl[IBD == l, paste0(q0, "_INT") := as.integer(cut(get(q0), c(0, q1, Inf)))]
  }
}
smpl # end result data.table
```

The major difference will be that the end result will have different row order than your original result.

Using this line it should be faster:

```
smpl[IBD == l, paste0(q0, "_INT") := cut(get(q0), c(0, q1, Inf), labels = F)]
```

Comment: Thank you a ton for your answer. This will be a huge time saving. I tried both of them and in deed there is a huge reduction in time....Cut is doing the magic. the one with rbind is taking **0.05042601** seconds and the one with datatable is taking **0.09625602** seconds. So it seems the rbind is working better. I wanted to have your feedback on handling of NA. Will **cut** be able to also handle NAs present in either **inter1** OR **smpl**. Please suggest

Comment: @user1412 How do you want `NA` to be handled? if NA is in smpl, then everything should be fine. If NA is in inter1, then i think that some kind of workaround should be implemented before cut.

Comment: @user1412 `data.table` should be faster for large `N` (row count) and many `IBD` groups

Comment: If NA is in inter1, we would need to take the last available value, so for example if for IBD 5 var1a, we have values like 11,18,NA,NA then in this case we would have 3 codes <=11 = code 1, >11 &<= 18= code 2, >18 = code 3. Will the current code need some tweak for this scenario?

Comment: @user1412 I think that no, but see it for yourself.

Comment: I added few NAs for couple if variables and did a check and it is working fine. Thank you very much. As you said for large dataset data.table will be faster and will use the same (+1). Thank you once again!!

Answer (score 2):

There are two alternative approaches, *rolling join* and *update in a non-equi join*. Both are four to five times faster for the given sample dataset and less memory consuming than [minem's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51671018/3817004).

#### Non-equi join

It requires to create `start` - `end` intervals which is best done in long format

```
# create intervals in long format
long <- setDT(melt(inter1, "IBD", variable.name = "var"))
long <- rbind(long,
              long[, CJ(IBD = IBD, var = var, 
                        value = c(-.Machine$integer.max, .Machine$integer.max), 
                        unique = TRUE)])[
                          order(IBD, var, value)]
long <- long[, .(start = head(value, -1L), 
         end = tail(value, -1L),
         INT = 1:(.N - 1L)), 
     by = .(IBD, var)]
long
```

> ```
>      IBD   var       start        end INT
>   1:   1 var1a -2147483647          2   1
>   2:   1 var1a           2          4   2
>   3:   1 var1a           4          8   3
>   4:   1 var1a           8          9   4
>   5:   1 var1a           9 2147483647   5
>  ---                                     
> 246:  10 var5a -2147483647         29   1
> 247:  10 var5a          29         44   2
> 248:  10 var5a          44         45   3
> 249:  10 var5a          45         80   4
> 250:  10 var5a          80 2147483647   5
> ```

Note that the largest integer was used instead of `Inf` in order to avoid coersion from integer to double.

Now, we loop over the specified columns and do the non-equi join on each column. Each iteration adds a new result column:

```
v0int <- c("var1a","var2a","var3a","var4a","var5a")
setDT(smpl)
for (col in v0int) {
  smpl[long[var == col], 
       on = c("IBD", paste0(col, ">start"), paste0(col, "<=end")), 
       paste0(col, "_INT") := i.INT]
}


smpl[]
```

> ```
>         ID IBD CELL var1a var2a var3a var4a var5a var6a var7a var8a var9a loc bill var1a_INT var2a_INT var3a_INT var4a_INT var5a_INT
>    1:    1   7 6849    93    38   151   203    63    70    35     8     7  17    2         5         1         5         5         4
>    2:    2   9 2517   109   130    97   296    15    97    79   267   422   4    2         5         5         1         5         1
>    3:    3  10 9322    65    18   160   156    80   132    33    41   387   8    1         5         1         5         4         4
>    4:    4  10 7377   105     8    87   263   101   110   207   224   331  11    2         5         1         1         5         5
>    5:    5   4 6991    72   144   187   144   117   125   123    84    60   3    1         5         5         5         5         5
>   ---                                                                                                                               
> 4996: 4996   6 5129    56   188    21    74   105   133   192    45   284   5    1         5         5         1         3         5
> 4997: 4997   2 2657     8    50   127     6   119    81    60   250   209   3    2         2         5         5         1         5
> 4998: 4998   2 1473   128    90   156    74   203     5   198    63    10  17    1         5         5         5         5         5
> 4999: 4999   9 2120    66   141   170   256   151    68   205    97     8   9    2         5         5         5         5         5
> 5000: 5000   2 4555   109   102    92    98    11   107   104   210   266  14    2         5         5         5         5         1
> ```

Note that the join conditions (`on =`) are created dynamically as character strings.

#### Rolling join

[Frank has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51670643/code-optimization-data-table-current-for-loop-with-multiple-reference-to-be-o/51675804?noredirect=1#comment90314858_51675804) that a *rolling join* would also be applicable here as there are no gaps in the intervals.

The OP has specified *right closed* intervals, e.g.,

```
if smpl$var1a > 11 & smpl$var1a <= 18 then var1a_INT = 2
```

Therefore, we need a *backward* rolling join which uses the `end` values of the intervals.

In a regular join, the join parameters must match exactly. In a backward rolling join, if there is no exact match so that the value falls in the gap between two `end` values, then the *next observation is carried backwards* (NOCB).

```
long <- setDT(melt(inter1, "IBD", variable.name = "var", value.name = "end"))
long <- rbind(long,
              long[, CJ(IBD = IBD, var = var, end = .Machine$integer.max, 
                        unique = TRUE)])
setorder(long, IBD, var, end)
long[, INT := rowid(IBD, var)]

v0int <- c("var1a","var2a","var3a","var4a","var5a")
setDT(smpl)
for (col in v0int) {
  smpl[, paste0(col, "_INT") := long[var == col][
    smpl, on = c("IBD", paste0("end==", col)), 
    roll = -Inf, x.INT]]
}
```

#### Benchmark

The non-equi join and the rolling join is compared against the two fastest variants of [minem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51671018/3817004), the ones which update `smpl` by reference to avoid repeated calls to `rbind()`.

The results are equal except for a different order of rows.

As all solutions update `smpl` by reference, all benchmark runs start with a fresh `copy()` of the original dataset.

```
library(bench)
my_check <- function(x, y) {
  all.equal(x[order(ID)], y[order(ID)])
}

v0int <- c("var1a","var2a","var3a","var4a","var5a")
bm <- mark(
  rj = {
    smpl <- copy(smpl0)
    long <- setDT(melt(inter1, "IBD", variable.name = "var", value.name = "end"))
    long <- rbind(long,
                  long[, CJ(IBD = IBD, var = var, end = .Machine$integer.max, 
                            unique = TRUE)])
    setorder(long, IBD, var, end)
    long[, INT := rowid(IBD, var)]
    setDT(smpl)
    for (col in v0int) {
      smpl[, paste0(col, "_INT") := long[var == col][
        smpl, on = c("IBD", paste0("end==", col)), 
        roll = -Inf, x.INT]]
    }
    smpl[]
  },
  nej = {
    smpl <- copy(smpl0)
    long <- setDT(melt(inter1, "IBD", variable.name = "var"))
    long <- rbind(long,
                  long[, CJ(IBD = IBD, var = var, 
                            value = c(-.Machine$integer.max, .Machine$integer.max), 
                            unique = TRUE)])[
                              order(IBD, var, value)]
    long <- long[, .(start = head(value, -1L), 
                     end = tail(value, -1L),
                     INT = 1:(.N - 1L)), 
                 by = .(IBD, var)]

    setDT(smpl)
    for (col in v0int) {
      smpl[long[var == col], 
           on = c("IBD", paste0(col, ">start"), paste0(col, "<=end")), 
           paste0(col, "_INT") := i.INT]
    }
    smpl[]
  },
  minem1 = {
    smpl <- copy(smpl0)
    setDT(smpl) # convert smpl to data.table
    setkey(smpl, IBD) # setkey on IBD for faster `IBD == l` operation
    for (l in (unique(inter1$IBD))) {
      for (k in 1:length(v0int)) {
        q0 <- v0int[k]
        q1 <- sort(inter1[inter1$IBD == l, q0])
        smpl[IBD == l, paste0(q0, "_INT") := as.integer(cut(get(q0), c(0, q1, Inf)))]
      }
    }
    smpl[]
  },
  minem2 = {
    smpl <- copy(smpl0)
    setDT(smpl) # convert smpl to data.table
    setkey(smpl, IBD) # setkey on IBD for faster `IBD == l` operation
    for (l in (unique(inter1$IBD))) {
      for (k in 1:length(v0int)) {
        q0 <- v0int[k]
        q1 <- sort(inter1[inter1$IBD == l, q0])
        smpl[IBD == l, paste0(q0, "_INT") := cut(get(q0), c(0, q1, Inf), labels = FALSE)]
      }
    }
    smpl[]
  },
  check = my_check, 
  min_time = 1
)

bm
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 14
>   expression      min     mean  median     max `itr/sec` mem_alloc  n_gc n_itr total_time result memory time  gc   
>   <chr>      <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt> <dbl> <int>   <bch:tm> <list> <list> <lis> <lis>
> 1 rj             20ms   22.5ms    22ms    28ms     44.5     1.73MB     3    41      921ms <data~ <Rpro~ <bch~ <tib~
> 2 nej          25.3ms   28.3ms  28.6ms  30.9ms     35.4     2.31MB     2    20      566ms <data~ <Rpro~ <bch~ <tib~
> 3 minem1      106.2ms  113.8ms 110.3ms 129.9ms      8.79     6.4MB     2     7      797ms <data~ <Rpro~ <bch~ <tib~
> 4 minem2       98.8ms  101.8ms 101.6ms 106.3ms      9.83    5.66MB     3     7      712ms <data~ <Rpro~ <bch~ <tib~
> ```

The rolling join is about five times faster than [minem's solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51671018/3817004), the non-equi join is four times faster. In addition, two to four times less memory is  allocated.

```
ggplot2::autoplot(bm)
```

[image]

Comment: Cool, never seen a time + mem benchmarker. "It requires to create start - end intervals" -- the intervals partition the real line, so just specifying one (start or end) and doing a rolling join seems to fit... which seems like it should be even more efficient.

Comment: @Frank, backward rolling join added to answer & benchmark. Another 25% gain in speed and less allocated memory. The difficult part was to figure out that I had to use a backward rolling join in order to cope with the right closed intervals.

Comment: @Uwe, Thank you for your answer and time looking into this. Though it is slightly heavy code for me, I will go thru it and understand so that I can make use of the same. I can see there is lot for me to learn from you code. Thank you once again !!